# print regards following functions as arguments

Tags: haskell, monads, haskell-platform

So I'm learning Haskell and have a broader programm which i want to run, but I managed to narrow down why it doesn't work to this problem:

```
putSentence:: String -> IO ()
putSentence sentence = print sentence

func 0 =  putSentence "Sample Text."
func x = if 3 == x then putSentence "Three." func (x-1) else putSentence "Not three." func (x-1)
```

The above code doesn't compile because putSentence takes the following `func (x-1)` as an additional argument. This is the first time Haskell did it like that for me, and I already tried shuffling the priority around with parentheses and $, but didn't find a way to fix it, so help would be appreciated.

Comment: It will make it easier for others to answer if you provide the compiler output showing the failure rather than just saying it doesn't compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression

```
putSentence "Three." func (x-1)
```

calls `putSentence` with three arguments: `"Three."`, `func`, and `(x-1)`. This is wrong.

What you probably want to do is to perform the IO actions one after another. For that you can use `>>`:

```
putSentence "Three." >> func (x-1)
```

Alternatively, use a `do` block:

```
do putSentence "Three."
   func (x-1)
```

E.g.

```
func x = if 3 == x
   then do
      putSentence "Three."
      func (x-1)
   else do
      putSentence "Not three."
      func (x-1)
```

Comment: This works wonderfully. I was sure I already tried making them into a do block, but maybe I messed up the formatting. Thanks alot!

Comment: @NinjaNinjaNinja Indentation matters after `do`: every action-line must start exactly on the same indentation level. (Instead the `if/then/else`, on its own, does not care about indentation.)

Answer (score 2):

You need a `do` block in order to sequence `IO` actions*

Try this instead:

```
func 0 = putSentence "Sample Text."
func x = if 3 == x
            then do
               putSentence "Three."
               func (x-1)
            else do
               putSentence "Not three."
               func (x-1)
```

*that's not strictly speaking true, as `do` blocks are just syntactic sugar for monadic functions, mainly the `(>>=)` operator. But `do` notation is often the easiest and most readable way, and certainly the easiest one to understand when you're first learning.

For a greater understanding of doing simple intput and output in Haskell, I would recommend the following [chapter](http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output) of the excellent Learn You a Haskell. Indeed I would recommend the entire book.